# No arranca proyecto java en servidor JBOSS, este es el debug:

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

14:02:36,738 INFO  [AbstractJBossASServerBase] Server Configuration:

```
JBOSS_HOME URL: file:/C:/Users/Administrator/jboss-6.1.0.Final/
Bootstrap: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
Common Base: $JBOSS_HOME\common/
Common Library: $JBOSS_HOME\common/lib/
Server Name: default
Server Base: $JBOSS_HOME\server/
Server Library: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/lib/
Server Config: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/conf/
Server Home: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/
Server Data: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/data/
Server Log: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/log/
Server Temp: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/tmp/
```

> 14:02:36,738 INFO  [AbstractServer] Starting: JBossAS [6.1.0.Final
>   "Neo"] 14:02:41,045 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.8.0_40,Oracle
>   Corporation 14:02:41,045 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25) 14:02:41,045 INFO 
>   [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   25.40-b25,Oracle Corporation 14:02:41,045 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1,amd64 14:02:41,045 INFO 
>   [ServerInfo] VM arguments:
>   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:52997 -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss AS 6.1 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Administrator\jboss-6.1.0.Final\lib\endorsed
>   -Djava.library.path=C:/Users/Administrator/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/native
>   -Dlogging.configuration=file:C:/Users/Administrator/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/logging.properties
>   -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252  14:02:41,154 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized 14:02:53,176 INFO  [AbstractServerConfig] JBoss Web
>   Services - Stack CXF Server 3.4.1.GA 14:02:53,215 WARN 
>   [AbstractKernelController] Broken callback:
>   ClassSingleCallbackItem@10d3e1e8{name=interface
>   org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.DescriptorProcessor
>   whenRequired=ControllerState@3af91537{Installed}
>   dependentState=ControllerState@3af91537{Installed}
>   attributeName=setProcessor
>   owner=AbstractKernelControllerContext@326adf9a{
>   metadata=AbstractBeanMetaData@59a7b19e{name=JMSDescriptorDeployer
>   bean=org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.JMSDescriptorDeployer
>   properties=
>   classLoader=BeanMetaDataDeployer$DeploymentClassLoaderMetaData@15d617f{classloader=null}
>   constructor=null autowireCandidate=true
>   installCallbacks=[method=setProcessor,
>   method=setParser]}name=JMSDescriptorDeployer
>   target=org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.JMSDescriptorDeployer@fe40fcd
>   state=Installed depends=AbstractDependencyInfo@5686f046{}}
>   signature=org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.DescriptorProcessor}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jboss.wsf.framework.deployment.jms.WebservicesDescriptorProcessorImpl
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.jms.JMSDescriptorProcessor     at
>   org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.JMSDescriptorDeployer.setProcessor(JMSDescriptorDeployer.java:33)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) [:1.8.0_40]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [:1.8.0_40]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [:1.8.0_40]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [:1.8.0_40]   at
>   org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:305)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ClassSingleCallbackItem.ownerCallback(ClassSingleCallbackItem.java:78)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1887)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1937)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1092)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:182)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:58)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827)
>   [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]     at
>   org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417)
>   [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
>
> 14:02:53,589 WARN  [AbstractKernelController] Broken callback:
>   ClassSingleCallbackItem@2bd30ae4{name=interface
>   org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.DescriptorProcessor
>   whenRequired=ControllerState@3af91537{Installed}
>   dependentState=ControllerState@3af91537{Installed}
>   attributeName=setProcessor
>   owner=AbstractKernelControllerContext@393de649{
>   metadata=AbstractBeanMetaData@4c249637{name=WSDescriptorDeployer
>   bean=org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDescriptorDeployer
>   properties=
>   classLoader=BeanMetaDataDeployer$DeploymentClassLoaderMetaData@4b283a6b{classloader=null}
>   constructor=null autowireCandidate=true
>   installCallbacks=[method=setProcessor,
>   method=setParser]}name=WSDescriptorDeployer
>   target=org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDescriptorDeployer@42ebe155
>   state=Installed depends=AbstractDependencyInfo@632d553f{}}
>   signature=org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.DescriptorProcessor}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.jms.JMSDescriptorProcessorImpl
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.webservices.WebservicesDescriptorProcessor
>     at
>   org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDescriptorDeployer.setProcessor(WSDescriptorDeployer.java:33)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) [:1.8.0_40]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [:1.8.0_40]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [:1.8.0_40]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [:1.8.0_40]   at
>   org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:305)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.SingleCallbackItem.changeCallback(SingleCallbackItem.java:67)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractCallbackItem.changeCallback(AbstractCallbackItem.java:80)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.OwnerCallbackItem.changeCallback(OwnerCallbackItem.java:116)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1951)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1092)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:182)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:58)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827)
>   [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]     at
>   org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417)
>   [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
>
> 14:02:54,806 INFO  [JSFImplManagementDeployer] Initialized 3 JSF
>   configurations: [Mojarra-1.2, MyFaces-2.0, Mojarra-2.0] 14:03:12,118
>   WARNING [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform,
>   it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux,
>   install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal 14:03:12,737 INFO 
>   [JMXConnector] starting JMXConnector on host localhost:1090
>   14:03:13,470 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
>   14:03:15,722 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] live server is starting with
>   configuration HornetQ Configuration
>   (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=C:\Users\Administrator\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\default\data/hornetq/journal,bindingsDirectory=C:\Users\Administrator\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\default\data/hornetq/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\Users\Administrator\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\default\data/hornetq/largemessages,pagingDirectory=C:\Users\Administrator\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\default\data/hornetq/paging)
>   14:03:15,737 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] Waiting to obtain live lock
>   14:03:15,943 INFO  [JournalStorageManager] Using NIO Journal
>   14:03:15,974 WARNING [HornetQServerImpl] Security risk! It has been
>   detected that the cluster admin user and password have not been
>   changed from the installation default. Please see the HornetQ user
>   guide, cluster chapter, for instructions on how to do this.
>   14:03:16,286 INFO  [FileLockNodeManager] Waiting to obtain live lock
>   14:03:16,286 INFO  [FileLockNodeManager] Live Server Obtained live
>   lock 14:03:17,987 INFO  [NettyAcceptor] Started Netty Acceptor version
>   3.2.3.Final-r${buildNumber} localhost:5455 for CORE protocol 14:03:17,987 INFO  [NettyAcceptor] Started Netty Acceptor version
>   3.2.3.Final-r${buildNumber} localhost:5445 for CORE protocol 14:03:17,987 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] Server is now live 14:03:17,987
>   INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] HornetQ Server version 2.2.5.Final
>   (HQ_2_2_5_FINAL_AS7, 121) [130bb783-b7e8-11e7-a2bd-00163e21d2a2]
>   started 14:03:18,159 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase:
>   http://localhost:8083/ 14:03:19,407 INFO  [jbossatx] ARJUNA-32010
>   JBossTS Recovery Service (tag: JBOSSTS_4_14_0_Final) - JBoss Inc.
>   14:03:19,423 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12324 Start RecoveryActivators
>   14:03:20,299 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12296 ExpiredEntryMonitor running
>   at mar, 24 oct 2017 14:03:20 14:03:20,519 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12310
>   Recovery manager listening on endpoint 127.0.0.1:4712 14:03:20,519
>   INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12344 RecoveryManagerImple is ready on port 4712
>   14:03:20,519 INFO  [jbossatx] ARJUNA-32013 Starting transaction
>   recovery manager 14:03:20,557 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12163 Starting
>   service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService on port
>   4713 14:03:20,558 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12337
>   TransactionStatusManagerItem host: 127.0.0.1 port: 4713 14:03:20,685
>   INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12170 TransactionStatusManager started on port
>   4713 and host 127.0.0.1 with service
>   com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService 14:03:20,810 INFO 
>   [jbossatx] ARJUNA-32017 JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version -
>   tag: JBOSSTS_4_14_0_Final) - JBoss Inc. 14:03:20,934 INFO  [arjuna]
>   ARJUNA-12202 registering bean jboss.jta:type=ObjectStore. 14:03:21,933
>   INFO  [AprLifecycleListener] The Apache Tomcat Native library which
>   allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on
>   the java.library.path:
>   C:/Users/Administrator/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/native

Comment: Prueba con: file:///C:/Users/Administrator/jboss-6.1.0.Final/

Comment: Luce a un problema de JBoss. Esta es la excepción que necesitas buscar: `org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.jms.JMSDescriptorProcessorImpl cannot be cast to org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.webservices.WebservicesDescriptorProcessor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según veo [en este hilo de la web de JBoss](https://developer.jboss.org/message/752678#752678), hay un problema al intentar usar Java 7 o superior con JBoss 6.1.0

Una solución puede ser cambiar en el fichero  `JBOSS_HOME/server/<node>/deployers/jbossws.deployer/META-INF/stack-agnostic-jboss-beans.xml` los siguientes beans:

```
 <!-- deployers -->
  <bean name="WSDescriptorDeployer" class="org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDescriptorDeployer">
    <!-- <incallback method="setProcessor"/> -->
    <property name="processor"><inject bean="WSDescriptorProcessor"/></property>
    <incallback method="setParser"/>
  </bean>


  <bean name="JMSDescriptorDeployer" class="org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.JMSDescriptorDeployer">
    <!-- <incallback method="setProcessor"/> -->
    <property name="processor"><inject bean="CXFJMSDescriptorProcessor"/></property>
    <incallback method="setParser"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: he modificado los beans que comentabas ahora me aparece esto pero sigue sin ponerse activo el servidor. Me aparece ahora esto:

Comment: En el stack trace dice que está usando Java 8

Comment: @Pablo , ya he actualizado la pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: @adrian Mea culpa, si tienes un nuevo error mejor crea una nueva pregunta